# Expected value of type Entity for association field got "string" instead

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to insert into my Reviews table, within my controller I have:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if($id != null)
    {
        // Create a new Review entity
        $review = new Review();

        $form = $this->createForm(ReviewType::class, $review,[
            'action' => $request->getUri()
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {

            $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $review->setPosted(new \DateTime());
            $review->setBookID($id);
            $review->setUserID($this->getUser());
            $manager->persist($review);
            $manager->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('ReviewBookBundle:Book:index.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

However on the line `$review->setBookID($id);` i get this error:

```
Expected value of type "Review\BookBundle\Entity\Book" for association field "Review\ReviewsBundle\Entity\Review#$bookID", got "string" instead.
```

How do i overcome this issues? Since I've tried creating a Book entity and setting the bookID and then passing the Book entity into the $review-setBookID, like so:

```
$review->setBookID($book);
```

but that still doesn't work?

Comment: In your Review entity, do you have a "setBook" method, which could have one argument (Book Entity) ?

Comment: @LucasDelobelle That is a good idea, let me try that!

Comment: @LucasDelobelle Could you please guide me to implementing this please?

Comment: @LucasDelobelle Could you please guide me to implementing this please?

Comment: Let's try $review->setBook($book); where $book is the Book itself (instance of Book Entity), not the id. Doctrine is smart, would do the link via the ManyToOne/OneToMany association you must have set

Comment: @LucasDelobelle Within the setBook function what should i set $book to?

Comment: You must have a $book field in your review Entity, so maybe you can try $this->book = $book in your setBook method

Comment: @LucasDelobelle I get this error: Annotation @ORM\OneToMany is not allowed to be declared on method Reviewr\ReviewsBundle\Entity\Review::setBook(). You may only use this annotation on these code elements: PROPERTY.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131919/discussion-between-ktov-and-lucas-delobelle).

Comment: Look at LugiHaue answer, it should work this way :) don't write the annotation on the setBook method but on the $book attribute. You also have to set a link annotation on your Book entity where you must have a reviews attribute

Comment: @LucasDelobelle It doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

Add this in your Review Entity:

```
/**
 * @var Book
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourBundle\Entity\Book", inversedBy="review", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $book;

/**
 * @return Book
 */
public function getBook()
{
    return $this->book;
}

/**
 * @param $book
 */
public function setBook($book)
{
    $this->book = $book;
}
```

And use:

```
$review->setBook($book);
```

`$book` must be instance of `Book` Entity

**Edit**

Book Entity:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @var Review
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="YourBundle\Entity\Review", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="review_id", mappedBy="book", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $reviews;

/**
 * @return Review
 */
public function getReviews()
{
    return $this->reviews;
}

/**
 * @param Review $review
 */
public function addReview(Review $review)
{
    $this->reviews->add($review);
}

/**
 * @param Review $review
 */
public function removeReview(Review $review)
{
    $this->reviews->removeElement($review);
}
```

Comment: OneToMany mapping on field 'book' requires the 'mappedBy' attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't the inversedBy for the book be "reviews" rather than "review"

Comment: Yes, I think this should be "reviews", since it's the name of the target entity's attribute (here it is the "reviews" attribute located in "YourBundle\Entity\Book"). Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $review->addBook() and pass book object not ID.